# Passenger woul'nt install apache module through rvm

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

I have a server which has passenger working with apache2 and ruby 1.8.7 as system default.

Now I have to upgrade a rails 2 app to rails 3.

so I installed rvm and its installed in /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm.

Then I used rvm use 1.9.2@global.

Next I installed passenger with rvmsudo gem install passenger. It got installed.

Whenever I run rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module, It would give me this message.

Checking for required software...

- GNU C++ compiler... found at /usr/bin/g++
- Curl development headers with SSL support... found
- OpenSSL development headers... found
- Zlib development headers... found
- Ruby development headers... found
- OpenSSL support for Ruby... found
- RubyGems... found
- Rake... found at /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p320/rake
- rack... found
- Apache 2... found at /usr/sbin/httpd
- Apache 2 development headers... found at /usr/sbin/apxs
- Apache Portable Runtime (APR) development headers... found at /usr/bin/apr-1-config
- Apache Portable Runtime Utility (APU) development headers... found at /usr/bin/apu-1-config

---

Compiling and installing Apache 2 module...
cd /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.12
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p320/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes

## /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p320/rake apache2:clean apache2 RELEASE=yes

/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p320/rake: line 6: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin/rake: Success

---

It looks like something went wrong

Please read our Users guide for troubleshooting tips:

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.12/doc/Users guide Apache.html

If that doesn't help, please use our support facilities at:

http://www.modrails.com/

We'll do our best to help you.

I don't know what went wrong. Help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I updated yum and everything works like butter now.